# Javascript's link rel="preload" is getting ignored by <script> tag

Tags: javascript, preload

I'm trying to preload some scripts and fonts using the `link rel="preload"` html element. I also have a `<script>` tag further down in the page.

When I do this, both the preload AND the script tag both download the content from the same resource.

I thought the script tag would be smart enough to cancel or wait for the preload to complete.

-or-

Does the script tag 'fire off' because the preload hasn't completed .. and as such, we see two requests for the same resource?

here's some timing data ...

[image]

Also, not sure what my options are if the answer is based on my second-guess, above.

Comment: My understanding is that `link rel="preload"` will download the resource anyways and cache it. And - considering the timings - your `script` tag is just retrieving the cached version.

Comment: Perhaps to get a clearer idea of what is happening, why not put a `console.log` statement at the top of each script. This will give you a clearer idea of the order of things.

Comment: @leo.fcx "your script tag is just retrieving the cached version" <-- um, you sure? if it was cached, wouldn't it say (`retrieved from disk`) or something? It's saying `200` which suggests that it's going to the internet...

Comment: @LeeTaylor What would that achieve? (edit: and no, I'm not trying to sound rude, even though it might sound it.) Right now, I can see exactly what is happening with the Waterfall timings, right? With the above, I'm assuming that the first "time" is the pre-load .. which the second "time" (which kicks off DURING the loading of the first "time") is the script reference.

Comment: This partially confirms what I say: `When the browser sees the preload, it starts a high priority download for the resource, so that by the time it's actually needed it's either already fetched or partly there.` ... Read [source](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/modulepreload)

Comment: @leo.fcx oh nice reference! Check out the next paragraph ... "`There are several credentials modes for resources, and in order to get a cache hit they must match, otherwise you end up fetching the resource twice. Needless to say, double-fetching is bad, because it wastes the user's bandwidth and makes them wait longer, for no good reason.`" Notice how they talk about cache/hit/miss/double-fetching! So maybe I was right after all...